# Customizing jQuery theme, but some CSS is not being applied

Tags: css, jquery-ui, customization

I am customizing a jQuery theme to add custom icons for some buttons. Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Apeksha82/nctPc/2 (My custom CSS definitions are at the bottom)

What I have done is taken some CSS definitions which were already there, and made them more specific like so:

```
.black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
background-image: url("http://jqueryui.com/resources/images/themeroller/st-stephens.jpg");
```

}

"lnkHeader" is a class defined by me. Some of my custom styles are not being applied and I cannot figure out why. e.g.

`.black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-icon .menu-home {
    background-position: 50px 50px;
}`

I have made sure the button has all these classes either assigned to itself or to its parents. I have tried switching around the order of the classes in the CSS definition file. If I remove "lnkHeader" from the above definitions, the CSS for hover image works, but background-position and margin still does not.

> `.black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-icon .menu-newPage {
>       background-position: 10px 10px;
>   }
>   .black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon, .black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-button-text-icons .ui-icon {
>       margin-top: -14px;
>   }`

I need lnkHeader to be part of the definition so that my customizations do not affect other buttons.

I believe I have considered the two factors that affect CSS - inheritance & specificity, in the way I have defined my custom CSS. But obviously I am missing something. Please help. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html, you have this item:

```
<div class="black-tie"><a class="lnkHeader">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon menu-home"></span>
</a></div>
```

What it looks like you need to select this `<span>` is

```
.black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-icon.menu-home { ... }
```

(with no space between `.ui-icon` and `.menu-home`)

And then similarly for the other elements:

```
.black-tie .lnkHeader .ui-icon.menu-newPage { ... }
.black-tie .lnkHeader.ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon { ... }
```

I don't see anything with the class `.ui-button-text-icons` in the fiddle, so can't say what the last selector's supposed to match.

---

- **Whitespace** between selectors means *children*; eg. `.ui-icon .menu-home` means all tags with `class=menu-home` that are children (direct or descended) of tags with `class=ui-icon`
- **No whitespace** means *same* DOM element and is equivalent to a logic AND; e.g. `.ui-icon.menu-home` means all tags which have both classes: `class="ui-icon menu-home"`;

  You can also combine different types of selectors this way. For example, the following selector: `div.my-class[data=my-data]` would only match `<div class=my-class data=my-data>`
- Direct children are selected with **the *greater than* sign** -- and with this, whitespace doesn't matter; eg. `.lnkHeader > .ui-icon` means all tags with `class=ui-icon` which are one level below tags with `class=lnkHeader`

You can find a full reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks! That helped me get the background-position applied. Still trying to get the other attributes to work. The class `.ui-button-text-icons` is automatically applied as a result of the call to jQuery button widget.

Comment: Update: I have been able to resolve all issues using the same technique, of removing the space between two CSS class names. Thanks a bunch for that! Does removing the space imply "direct child"? I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on why it works the way it does.

Comment: @Apeksha Edited into answer; also included a link to the w3schools page